# What is the best approach to clone objects properties when using map()?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to add a new property (contactDetails.countryName) and assign a value to a nested object stored in an array called users using the function map().

I've recently learned that I should use the spread operator (...) and then create / assign the new property in order to avoid mutating my original array of objects so I've developed 2 different implementations for this but I'm not really confident I'm following the best practices to accomplish I want to regarding the semantic and performance.

What would be the best approach to accomplish what I want to do in your opinion?

```
const countries = [
  { id: 3, countryName : "UK" },
  { id: 4, countryName : "Spain" },
  { id: 6, countryName : "Germany"}
];


const users = [
  { id : 1,
    name: "Douglas Camp",
    dateOfBirth: "23-06-1984",
    contactDetails:
      {
        country: 3,
        phone: "7373724997"
      }
  },
  {
    id : 2,
    name: "Martin Stein",
    dateOfBirth: "19-08-1992",
    contactDetails:
      {
        country: 6,
        phone: "3334343434"
      }
  },
];


const usersData = users.map(user=> {

// Version 1 : using spreading operator twice 

const newUser = {
    ...user,
    contactDetails: {
      ...user.contactDetails,
      countryName: countries.find(c=> c.id == user.contactDetails.country).countryName
    }
  };  
  return newUser;
});

// Version 2: copying the original object property and using spread operator only for cloning the nested object properties

const newUser = {
    id: user.id,
    name: user.name,
    dateOfBirth: user.dateOfBirth,
    contactDetails: {
      ...user.contactDetails,
      countryName: countries.find(c=> c.id == user.contactDetails.country).countryName
    }
  };

console.log(users);
console.log(usersData);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach you can consider:

- First of all I would [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) the countries to a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) so you can get them via `key`/`value` or in this case by `countries.get(key)` and avoid filtering that array every time.
- You can map through the users and for each one create a new object. In this case I call them `accounts`.
- You can also consider using [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)
- Note that both `...` operator and `Object.assign` are **shallow clone approaches**. They do not recursively clone the nested objects/children. For that you can use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` etc.

```js
let countries = [
  { id: 3, countryName : "UK" },
  { id: 4, countryName : "Spain" },
  { id: 6, countryName : "Germany"}
].reduce((r,{id, countryName}) => (r.set(id, countryName), r), new Map()) // reduce with Map

let users = [ { id : 1, name: "Douglas Camp", dateOfBirth: "23-06-1984", contactDetails: { country: 3, phone: "7373724997" } }, { id : 2, name: "Martin Stein", dateOfBirth: "19-08-1992", contactDetails: { country: 6, phone: "3334343434" } }, ];

let accounts = users.map(user => Object.assign({}, user, {  // <-- map through
  contactDetails: { 
   ...user.contactDetails,
   countryName: countries.get(user.contactDetails.country)  // <-- get by key
  }
}))

users[0].id = 2  // <-- modify users
users[0].contactDetails.phone = "00000"

console.log(users, accounts) // <-- no changes to accounts
```

Notice when we update the `users[0].id` and `users[0].contactDetails.phone` the accounts values did not update.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. I was actually also concerned about using find() .

Answer (score 0):

I normally use version 1, the spread operator twice. I also would consider checking out [immer](https://github.com/immerjs/immer) which allows you to do mutable updates on a cloned draft and handles merging it back for you.

```
const newUser = immer(user, draft => {
  draft.contactDetails.countryName = countries.find(
    c => c.id == user.contactDetails.country).countryName
  )
})
```

Just edit the specific property you want and immer handles copying the rest of it.

Answer (score 0):

Cloning and merging MapsSection
Just like Arrays, Maps can be cloned:

```
var original = new Map([
  [1, 'one']
]);

var clone = new Map(original);

console.log(clone.get(1)); // one
console.log(original === clone); // false. Useful for shallow comparison
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally like to use Version 1, as it makes your code much less redundant and easier to read. It also passes all the properties of  'user' down to newUser.